# How to match negative lookbehind with unknown characters between?

Tags: javascript, regex, cypress, negative-lookbehind

I need to match all `.get('asfd')`, but only in the case where `.wait(.*)` doesn't exist beforehand.

```
.wait(500).get('asdf') // shouldn't match
.asdf('asdf').get('asdf') // should match
```

Unfortunately, negative look-behinds don't support quantifiers, so I'm not sure how to describe the void between `.wait(` and `).get('asdf')` for `\d*`

What's the approach for matching this unquantifiable area?

I figure I need some way to describe that there wasn't a `wait` behind the last set of parenthesis, but is there a simple way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it took quite a lot of experimenting, and asking this question helped to clarify the situation.

The answer is to **describe the in-between: separate from the look-behind**.

```
(?<!wait)
(?:\([^)]*\))
(\.get\(.*\))
```

That second section allows any character until a parenthesis. Sometimes, the first parenthesis appears inside quotes, and should be ignored. Not accounting for escaped quotes, my entire regex became:

```
((?<!wait)\(.*\)\s*)(\.get\((?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')[^\)]*\))
```

And I use it to insert `.wait()` before/after `.get()` with match groups 1 (`$1`) and 2 (`$2`)

```
$1.wait(234)$2.wait(234)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be `.*(?<!wait)(?:\(.*\))(\.get\(.*\))`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a regex expert, but how about this?

`/^(?!\.wait\(\d+\)).*\.get\(.*\)/g`

**Explanation:**

`(?!` **Negative lookahead.** Specifies a group
        that can not match after the main expression (if it matches, the result is discarded).

`\.` **Escaped character.** Matches a "." character (char code
            46).

`w` **Character.** Matches a "w" character (char code 119).
            Case sensitive.

`a` **Character.** Matches a "a" character (char code 97).
            Case sensitive.

`i` **Character.** Matches a "i" character (char code 105).
            Case sensitive.

`t` **Character.** Matches a "t" character (char code 116).
            Case sensitive.

`\(` **Escaped character.** Matches a "(" character (char code
            40).

`\d`**Digit.** Matches any digit character (0-9).

`+` **Quantifier.** Match 1 or more of the preceding
            token.

`\)` **Escaped character.** Matches a ")" character (char code
            41).

`.` **Dot.** Matches any character except line breaks.

`*` **Quantifier.** Match 0 or more of the preceding
        token.

`\.` **Escaped character.** Matches a "." character (char code
        46).

`g` **Character.** Matches a "g" character (char code 103). Case
        sensitive.

`e` **Character.** Matches a "e" character (char code 101). Case
        sensitive.

`t` **Character.** Matches a "t" character (char code 116). Case
        sensitive.

`\(` **Escaped character.** Matches a "(" character (char code
        40).

`.` **Dot.** Matches any character except line breaks.

`*` **Quantifier.** Match 0 or more of the preceding
        token.

`\)` **Escaped character.** Matches a ")" character (char code
        41).